# How to remove #N/A that appears through out a worksheet? (VBA for excel Required)

Tags: excel, vba

I have to clear #N/A that happens through out my worksheet when ever i run my code. I'm not sure why and have been debugging for a while but to no avail. What i could do to remedy this problem is to delete it entirely from the page, where they happens randomly. If anyone know how to, do share a VBA code with me.

Codes of doing a simple copy and paste into another sheet

```
thevaluestocopy = Sheets("pivot").Cells(thefirstrow, 1) _
   .Resize(thelastrow - thefirstrow, 1)
    Worksheets("summary").Cells(3, 16) _
   .Resize(thelastrow - thefirstrow + 1, 16) = thevaluestocopy
```

I have nested that code with different Column because my pivot table changes most of the time. And when i copied for the 2nd time, #N/A appears.. Have no idea why and i believe this works work fine.

Comment: Please post some of your code. Chances are that if `#N/A` occurs in some cells as a result of running your code then there's a problem with your code.

Comment: I'm doing a simple copy and paste from a sheet to another.. but when it tries to do the same thing, values appear together with #N/A.. If you know why, do share it. I hope this isnt too short for you to understand what i'm trying to do, or maybe you could share with my how to copy a fixed column of values. Might solve that problem as well.

Comment: Does the Source Sheet has `#N/A`? If not, then you can use `PasteSpecial Values` to do a copy and paste as @mattboy suggested.

Comment: @user1204868 if the values you're pasting are the result of a formula then you'll need to paste special as mattboy suggests.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, there isnt any `#N/A` in my source sheet. I'm copying values from pivot table and definitely will be without any formulas. I have no idea why it actually just appears. Anyway, i think removing them should solve the problem for now...
@BrianDriscoll, nope, there is no formula..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run this line to remove any `#N/A` error values in the worksheet:

```
Cells.Replace "#N/A","",xlWhole
```

If the worksheet contains formulas you can try this:

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).Clear
```

Comment: This is pretty slow tho, I had to walk away to let it finish because I had lots of cells matching,.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but how about doing something like this instead? This is how I generally copy and paste, without problems.

```
Sheets("pivot").Range("your range").Copy
Worksheets("summary").Range("your range").PasteSpecial
```

UPDATE
If you still want to simply remove all the #N/As with your current code, you can use some code like this.

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(row, column)) Then Cells(row, column).ClearContents
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! I think it will be tough to have a "your range" way because values are not fixed so may need to run a few checks. Anyway, the removing is good enough

Comment: No problem. I'm not very familiar with the whole Resize thing you're doing but I believe this would still return a range in the end, so doing `Sheets("pivot").Cells(thefirstrow, 1).Resize(thelastrow - thefirstrow, 1).Copy` and `.PasteSpecial`should work.