# VBA to find N/A error and chenge it to zero

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that goes to a sheet in the file called transaction activity, look at column N and if it finds any N/A errors/values, it changes then to zero, else leave the values in the column alone.

```
 Sub errorcheck()



    Sheets("Transaction Activity").Visible = True
    Sheets("Transaction Activity").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    sNonBlank = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Transaction Activity").Range("N8:N1048576"))

    If IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Transaction Activity").Range("N8:N1048576").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value) Then
  If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Transaction Activity").Range("N8:N1048576").Offset(offsetCount, 0).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then
    Cells.Select = 0
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Brian

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this? Can't you just use the `IFERROR` function?

Comment: Firstly, if you are looking at a column "N" then you don't want to use Offset in your checks as that will move onto a different row/column...  You should also avoid `Select` as it'll just slow your code right down.  For setting a cell value you would use `.Value = 0` anyway and not `.Select`...  What you really need is a loop over the range, checking for the error with `IsError` and if you find one, replace the value with 0.  That's about as much help as I can give without doing what sounds a lot like a homework question for you :)

Comment: There is a legacy model that is now giving error in this colomn, to save time going through 1000s of line of VBA , I am just adding a patch to take care of the error, so that why need the VBA, the formulas are copied from several locations. Its a mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are formulas in the sheet you can use:

```
  Range("N:N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors).Clear
```

If not you could use

```
Range("N:N").replace "#N/A",0,xlwhole
```

This should do the trick.  Although, to avoid errors in the first place you could add

```
IFERROR(fx,0)
```

To your formulas without having to use VBA

This is very similar to another question [How to remove #N/A that appears through out...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703473/how-to-remove-n-a-that-appears-through-out-a-worksheet-vba-for-excel-required)

[Also replace info](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php)