# Combining 2 workbooks into 1 worksheet based on common row value

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks, one with Email and IP values and the 2nd one with Name and IP Value.
I'm trying to combine these two workbooks into one and to fit the names and emails to common IP's.

Screenshot: http://take.ms/0Y3wv

Example:

```
Workbook 1 has:
jack123@gmail.com 1.1.1.1
emilly444@gmail.com 2.2.2.2
```

Workbook 2 has:

```
John 12.12.12.12
Jack 1.1.1.1
Emily 2.2.2.2
```

The result should be:

```
(Discard John cause we don't have his IP in the 2nd workbook).
jack123@gmail.com 1.1.1.1 Jack
emilly444@gmail.com 2.2.2.2 Emily
```

Comment: Are those values all in the same column, or is email one column, IP another, and name a third?

Comment: One workbook has Email and IP (different columns) and the second workbook has Name and IP (different columns too).
So the values are not even in the same workbook.

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH` formulas could do the trick...

Comment: I'm a total newbie with everything regarding Excel, I have tried following this article guidelines with no success: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1347-excel-combine-rows-with-same-value.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another job for the **Vlookup function**.

First, something that could be done to make your life easier (personal experience) is to put the common column of data in "A" column position of Workbook 2.

If you want the output (with both data from Workbook 1 and 2) be output to Workbook 1, just use Vlookup:
 On column 3 (row 2) of workbook 1 (assuming your data is organized as in your example, and that, on Workbook 2, your column A has 1.1.1.1):

```
=Vlookup($B2,'Workbook2'!$A$1:$B$3,2,False)
```

Then drag the formula down to all the rows that have data.

What this code does:

**1:** $B2 will select the identifier in the Workbook 1

**2:** 'Workbook2'!$A$1:$B$3 will select the range where the data will be looked up (here you should just click on the workbook you want and select the data, than click "," and click back on the Workbook 1). Also, I used fixed references ($) so you could drag down the formula.

**3:** 2 is the column from which the function will retrieve the data.

**4:** False is just for an exact match.

You could do this for more columns of data, just pay attention to the identifier and to which column you are getting the data from.

For the data that is missing, you could write an if function in VBA to delete the row if a certain cell is #N/A (which will be the result you get, if you use the vlookup).

Comment: What if I have 230,000 rows of data? Launched this like 4 minutes ago, still loading :) How much till will it take? Will it even work?

Comment: Ok it worked after a few minutes! Thanks! Now regarding the #N/A fields, is there a way to delete the whole rows, not just the #N/A cells? I only found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703473/how-to-remove-n-a-that-appears-through-out-a-worksheet-vba-for-excel-required

Where should I run this? Developer -> Insert -> Module? It asks for a macro name.

Comment: It will still work, but will take longer. The other option that would increase the time significantly is coding a match up procedure in a VBA loop, using arrays.

I had to do something similar some months ago, the time dropped from to 5% when I used VBA arrays.

Comment: I think the one you linked only removes the #N/A cells. What I would recommend is creating a very brief VBA sub (in a module) with a loop that checks each cell in a column and deletes the whole row. Here it is important to loop from end to beginning, to avoid problems with the row deletions. This type of loop to delete columns based on a condition are most certainly already explained in another question.

Comment: I've tried `Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete` in a Sub and it stuck. I've also read that you can't run this on A LOT of data or it will erase everything. So I just saved it as `.csv` and handled everything with Notepad++. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help. If you want to automate the process, a backwards for loop, (or a loop within an array) would solve your problem. Again, don't forget that if you are going to delete columns, do it from bottom to the top, to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `INDEX` `MATCH` formula will do what you want,

`=INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(B1,Sheet2!B:B,0),1)`

[image]

This formula gets the required data from `Sheet2`. Now I leave the rest for you to google and find out how to get the data from a different workbook. Thats an easy task and a minute change to the formula. Let me know if you face any difficulty.